# Travel to France with refugee travel document

Tags: france, south-korea, refugees

I intend to travel to France with a South Korean refugee travel document. Can I do this?

Comment: What is your citizenship? Does your original nationality allow visa-free entry to France?

Answer (score 3):

South Korean nationals do not need a visa to visit France, but refugees do need a visa.

You may visit the [Embassy of France in Seoul](https://kr.ambafrance.org/Applying-for-a-short-stay-Schengen) web site for information on how to apply for the short-stay Schengen visa in South Korea.